# how to change screen resolution when application launches?

Tags: c#, wpf, screen-resolution

i am working on a POS applciation  with WPF,C#, SQLCE ,  VS 2010 .   I created a  bill entry form  with fixed window of 800 * 600  width and height.

but other windows in the project are made to work with  system resolutions. now i want to change the system resolution  to 800*600   when this bill entry form opens in  My POS application .  For  reporting and  maintenance of Stocks & Inventory  i used rich UI Controls with Window size maximazed but for BILL ENTRY FORM ( considering my needs) i kept its window size to 800*600 . when i open the form it looks very small in 1440*900 resolution. so i want to change system resolution to 800*600  whn this window opens and when this window closes it should return back to 1400*900  resolution .. is there any way to do this

Comment: You shouldn't be doing this.. its not a Full-screen Application like Game where you change your Resolution.. user will definitely not like it...and also its not a Good Development practice, ... By the way WPF is mature enough to allow you to create Resolution independent Solutions... Consider that.

Comment: but in POS Bill entry window will have only 10 entries. so i created this using ten rows of Textbox and binding to a obseravable collection . so the 10 rows of textbox  looks very small  . thats why i trying to put it in 800*600.

Comment: Put a Viewbox into you entry window. It will scale up (or down) whatever is inside: http://www.wpftutorial.net/ViewBox.html

Comment: @bitbonk  , link provided you is very helpfull , i will try this .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to change the desktop resolution. WPF is resolution independent and can scale everything the way you need it. It will look much better too.

For simple scaling you can use the Viewbox class:

```
<Window
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
    x:Name="Window"
    Title="MainWindow"
    Width="800" Height="600">
    <Viewbox>
        <ListView Height="150" Width="200">
            <ListViewItem>item 1</ListViewItem>
            <ListViewItem>item 2</ListViewItem>
        </ListView>
    </Viewbox>
</Window>
```

It will automatically scale whatever is inside to whatever size is avalibale:

[image: small]

[image: middle]

[image: large]

Answer (score 2):

It's not a good practice to programmatically change a users's settings - instead you should display a message to the user asking them to change the screen resolution themselves. If you really require a particular reolution, you can cancel the application load until they have changed it to the required setting.

**I strongly recommend Not to Do this**

But for your problem ...
Use this function `ChangeDisplaySettingsEx` from GDI(not easy, but have no builtin C# function for this) have a look here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd183413%28VS.85%29.aspx

You need to do a DLL import of  `"User32.dll"` to use this function.